# mining on geth using --mainnet

Tags: go-ethereum

So I synced geth and started mining from js attach on the mainnet directly without creating a private network. It mined some blocks and the ETH balance is showing up 30 in js console but I checked the same local account on etherscan.io and that says 0. It's creating private network necessary for mining eth, I would've thought since PN doesn't share data it wouldn't be in sync and may be used for test. So what do I have as balance ETH then? It doesn't fluctuate and is steady(+5 for each block). It's mining on the mainnet wrong since I assumed it would be better on a fully synced node. If the balance is real, how do I send it to ERC20 account wallet (I tried all ways, its giving error: gas required exceeds allowance(5024)?

Comment: From the details the node hasn't finishes syncing so the blocks being mined will be discarded when it finishes syncing because its PoW is surely much less that the whole ethereum history. It is not usable ether, it will not be accepted by anyone.

Comment: okay. but how do i mine real eth then?

Comment: The usual way to mine today is to have a GPU card and then use a mining pool, so you don't have to maintain a full node.